# Бот дискорд который выдает роли по нажатию на эмодзи выдает ошибку

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, role, emoji

> Я сделал бота дискорд который при нажатии на реакцию под любым постом дает определенную роль,
> когда я нажимаю на жмодзи в консоль выдается ошибка

Вот сам код:

```py
import discord
import config

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True


class DiscordBot(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Бот {self.user} в сети")

    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, paylood):
        if paylood.message.id == config.ID_POST:
            channel = self.get_channel(paylood.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(paylood.message_id)
            user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=paylood.user_id)
            emoji = str(paylood.emoji)

            try:
                role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLE_LIST(emoji))

                if len([i for i in user.roles if i.id not in config.USER_ROLES_LIST]) <= config.MAX_ROLES:
                    await user.add_roles(role)
                    print(f"{user.name} получил роль {role.name}")
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(paylood.emoji, user)
                    print(f"Ошибка! пользователь {user.name} пытался получить слишком много ролей")

            except Exception as _ex:
                print(repr(_ex))

    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, paylood):
        channel = self.get_channel(paylood.channel_id)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(paylood.message_id)
        user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, id=paylood.user_id)

        try:
            emoji = str(paylood.emoji)
            role = discord.utild.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLE_LIST[emoji])
            await user.remove_roles(role)
        except Exception as _ex:
            print(repr(_ex))


client = DiscordBot(intents=intents)
client.run(config.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Вот config.py

```py
BOT_TOKEN = "M"
ID_POST = 0
USER_ROLES_LIST = ()
MAX_ROLES = 3

ROLE_LIST = {
    "✅": 1051595649646338118, #Верифицированый
}
```

> Вот ошибка которая выдается в консоль после нажатия на эмодзи которая должна давать роль в дискорде:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hadji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hadji\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dsrolebot\rolebot.py", line 14, in on_raw_reaction_add
    if paylood.message.id == config.ID_POST:
AttributeError: 'RawReactionActionEvent' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Answer (score 0):

А с чего вы взяли, что у объекта `payload` будут такие же свойства, как и у контекста команды `ctx`? Конечно, это было бы логично, но на практике оказалось не так.

А ведь все, что нужно было сделать, это просто посмотреть список свойств объекта **[`RawReactionActionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction_add#discord.RawReactionActionEvent)** в документации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда видим, что из необходимого есть только свойство `message_id`. Имея `id`, сообщение можно получить используя объект канала, в котором оно находится. А для получения объекта канала есть вся необходимая информация:

```py
channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
```

Чтобы не натыкаться на подобные проблемы в будущем, рекомендую научиться пользоваться [**документацией**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9)